# OVERHEATING SILVERADO WHILE TOWING

Tags: engine, chevrolet, radiator, overheating, silverado

So recently I was trying to haul my wifes '03 Volkswagen Beetle with my '08 Silverado. The truck was pulling fine, plenty of power, no struggle as expected. Around the 100 mile mark my truck began overheating rather quickly, quickly hitting the red zone, I pulled on the side waiting about 30 minutes for it to cool, until I could get somewhere to unload her car. After unloading and just hauling the trailer there were no overheating issues, everything seemed fine. I also had a recent issue with hauling a couple hundred pounds of dirt, I could tell it was starting to get warm under the hood. My thought is probably a clogged radiator, but I'm curious if anyone might have alternative suggestions to what it could be, and maybe any specific things I can do to help prevent this down the road after clearing the radiator and possibly adding another/bigger cooling system.

Comment: do you have an external trans cooler?

Comment: It could be a number of things; clogged radiator, radiator cap beginning to fail, old contaminated coolant, blocked passages, worn water pump, etc. Sounds like it is time for a chemical flush on the cooling system.

Comment: Which specific Silverado model do you have? Engine size and fuel type would be great to know. Also, is this a 4wd model? If so, were you hauling in 4wd mode? What are the gear ratios for the truck? Which transmission? If you don't know a lot of this information, you can get a picture of the RPO codes, which would be located on the inside of the glove compartment door. That will tell us everything we'd need to know about it.

Comment: Does it have an electric radiator fan or a belt driven fan?